# Laravel 5 with eloquent relation callback function returning wrong records

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, callback, eloquent-relationship

Here is User Model

```
public function userpackages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserPackages');
}
```

Trying to get users packages form specific month and year but it returning all records.

```
$users = User::with(['team', 'userpackages' => function($package) use($month,$year) {
    $package->whereMonth('created_at', $month)->whereYear('created_at', $year);
}])->get();
```

Fetching

```
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
  $userpackages = $user->userpackages;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the query ? using `toSql()` instead of `get()`

Comment: Thanks for your time @John
$users = User::with(['team', 'userpackages' => function($package) use($month,$year) {
            $package->whereMonth('created_at', $month)->whereYear('created_at', $year);
        }])->where('id', 4776)->toSql();

"select * from `users` where `id` = ?"

Comment: Thanks @lagbox laravel/framework": "5.5.*

Comment: maybe I read your question wrong ... are you trying to limit users to only users that have userpackages that match that criteria? or only limit the eager loading of that relationship to just those userpackages that match that criteria?

Comment: Actually i want to fetch user team packages from specific month.
That is my team relation

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'referrer_id','id');
    }

Comment: if you are just trying to constrain the eager load of `userpackages` then what you have should be doing that ... not sure how `team` and `userpackages` is related

Comment: Can you please check here 
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/18122462?key=fbfe8ba9e9944b06d089ef01956fbd45

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/18122394?key=8f2f0a6795f86e5d72230f606ce47905


https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/18122540?key=c06673e8f0173e8ff4d194895ce6f859

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are filtering the eager load, but this does not affect the models returned. You need to repeat the filter using `whereHas()` to limit the models that are returned. In addition, functions like `whereDate()` can be very inefficient, especially if the column is indexed. I suggest using `whereBetween()` when searching a date range.

```php
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m", "$year-$month");
$range = [$date->startOfMonth(), $date->endOfMonth()];

$users = User::with('team')
    ->with(['userpackages' => fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', $range)])
    ->whereHas('userpackages', fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('created_at', $range)
    ->get();
```

To explain further:

- `User::with('userpackages')` returns all users, each with all of their packages.
- `User::with(['userpackages' => 'some condition'])` returns all users, each with some of their packages
- `User::whereHas('userpackages', 'some condition')` returns some users, each with all of their packages
- `User::(['userpackages' => 'some condition'])->whereHas('userpackages', 'some condition')` returns some users, each with some of their packages.