# search query laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to do search query on products and 3 related tables this is what i've done so far:

```
$products = Product::with(['categories', 'tags','stags'])

        ->when(request('search'), function($query) {
            return $query->where('title','like','%' . request('search') . '%');
        })

        ->when(request('category_id'), function ($query) {
            return $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) {
                return $q->where('id', request('category_id'));
            });
        })

        ->orderBy('place' , 'desc')
        ->paginate(12);
```

the problem is when i add queries for stag and tag:

```
$products = Product::with(['categories', 'tags','stags'])

        ->when(request('search'), function($query) {
            return $query->whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
                return $q->where('name', request('search'));
            })->orWhereHas('stags', function ($q) {
                return $q->where('name', request('search'));
            })->orWhere('title','like','%' . request('search') . '%');
        })

        ->when(request('category_id'), function ($query) {
            return $query->whereHas('categories', function ($q) {
                return $q->where('id', request('category_id'));
            });
        })

     

        ->orderBy('place' , 'desc')
        ->paginate(12);
```

laravel is ignoring my category_id query!

Comment: Laravel 9 is not yet released. Are you using ```dev``` version ?

Comment: If it's ignoring it, then most likely `request('category_id')` is false or null. Try `Log::info(request()->all())` before this code to see what variables the request contains.

Comment: sorry it's 8
my bad

Comment: everything is fine with requests both have values

Comment: I think you need to make the conditions inside the eager loading (with()) as well. Because the whereHas() just chooses which records to fetch, and after that the with() eager loads all the relations (dont taking the wherehas into account, because it had nothing with the eager loading to do). So try to add conditions to you with() method as well: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: @thephper is correct; I explained the relationship between `with()` and `whereHas()` filters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267675/1255289) a few weeks ago.

Comment: Also there's no need to `return` from the callback functions. Objects are passed by reference so the methods run inside the callback affect the original object. The return values are ignored.